# asp.net access class of form control in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

How can I access the class of the  control in code behind? I need to be able to change the value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the class attribute of your control like this:

```
string formClass = form1.Attributes["class"].ToString();
```

You can also assign to it like this:

```
form1.Attributes["class"] = "MyCSSClassName";
```

Remember that this will overwrite any existing classes applied to the element, so be sure to add them back in if your intention was to add to, not replace.  Something like:

```
form1.Attributes["class"] = "MyCSSClassName MyOtherClassName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `form1.Attributes["class"] = "newClass";`